# Keep background image fixed during scroll using css

Tags: css

How do I keep the background image fixed during a page scroll?  I have this CSS code, and the image is a background of the body and not `<div></div>`

```
body {
  background-position:center;
  background-image:url(../images/images5.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#background-properties

Comment: That would make the pic go off the center position

Comment: You might want to specify the y position as well as the x position then.

Comment: background: no-repeat-x no-repeat-y; does not seem to work, or if I am getting it wrong here

Comment: thanks, I need to play around with it, the image file is huge.

Comment: How can you avoid the imaging "zooming" when you apply `position: fixed` ?

Answer (score 20):

```
background-image: url("/your-dir/your_image.jpg");
min-height: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: the min-height and min-width are the key here

Answer (score 1):

Just add background-attachment to your code

```
body {
    background-position: center;
    background-image: url(../images/images5.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```