# How to set background image in css

Tags: css

I have set a of the whole body in css, but when you scroll down, the image ends and repeats again. Is there a way to make it so the image doesn't scroll with the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep background image fixed during scroll using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662039/keep-background-image-fixed-during-scroll-using-css)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
body{
    background: url(theURL) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```